# List of Hebrew Words in Aleph-Beis Order?

Tags: words, hebrew

To help me study Chumash, where can I find a downloadable list of most commonly used Hebrew shorashim in Aleph-Beis Order? (Rav Hirsch dictionary is phenomenal but I'm not going to retype the whole work)

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel this now seeks only roots that appear in Chumash

Comment: If helpful to you I have a list of Hebrew verbs and nouns according to frequency of occurrence in the Torah which I could upload. Feels more useful than classified alphabetically unless that order is important to you